# Need RegEx to filter anything except keyboard characters

Tags: c#, regex

In my application client is uploading data from MS word to Textarea. My RegEx skills are not so good :)

I need a RegEx to filter all the junk characters from string and the only acceptable input is characters from keyboard. 
i.e, A-Z, a-z, 0-9 and all the special chracters present on keyboard + all currency symbols.

EDIT: I want to allow only ascii codes including extended. http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: Which keyboard? Mine has `ä` on it. My friend's keyboard has `Ø`...

Comment: Can you share an example from your input?

Comment: Some people have chinese or cyrillic keyboards installed.

Comment: for example, my keyboard is able to produce all these characters: `příliš žluťoučký kůň úpěl ďábelské ódy` (and more).

Comment: For every character, there exists a keyboard layout that is able to produce that character.

Comment: Most keyboards contain the `backspace` key, and ASCII contains the `backspace` control character. Do you want to allow this one?

Comment: RegEx which will strip out everything except A-Z, a-z , 0-9 and following characters. ~ ` ! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) _ + | - = \ { } [ ] : " ; ' < > ? , . / –

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have checked the ASCII table and all printable symbols it contains are present on any standard keyboard.

It's hard to tell what defines "special characters present on the keyboard" but I assume you mean printable non-alphanumeric characters. While all the unicode whitespace characters (non-braking space, zero-width word non-joiner...) are indeed "special", they are absent from most keyboards. The backspace character, while present on most keyboards, is typically interpreted by the OS, so I assume you don't want that. A similar argument applies to the tab key: while the tab character is easier to obtain than the newline character, it can't normally be typed into a form input.

Concerning currency symbols, the character class `\p{Sc}` covers them, and C# regex seems to support this class

Non-US keyboards contain many more characters (symbols with diacritics, cyrillic, chinese/japanese/korean characters), but they don't match your description of "A-Z, a-z, 0-9 and all the special chracters present on keyboard + all currency symbols". Of special interest is the japanese end-of-sentence punctuation, which is a hollow circle instead of just a dot. However, while it matches your description, I believe you don't want that either.

C# also supports `\p{isBasicLatin}`, but that includes the ASCII control characters, which I assume you don't want.

To sum up: your description matches the entire printable ASCII range and the newline `\n`. To check a string is made out of these, use this regex:

```
^[\x20-\x7E\n\p{Sc}]$
```

Reflecting your edit, also consider all printable ASCII characters (most currency symbols are absent, `$` isn't) + newline

```
^[\x20-\x7E\n]$
```

or the entire ASCII range including the control characters and all ASCII whitespace:

```
^[\x00-\x7F]$
^[\p{isBasicLatin}]$
```

Ref:
[MSDN character classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/20bw873z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
[MSDN character escapes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/4edbef7e%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
[MSDN code example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/01escwtf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (adapted here):

> ```
> bool IsValid(string strIn)
> {
>     // Return true if strIn is in valid format.
>     return Regex.IsMatch(strIn, @"^[\x20-\x7E\n\p{Sc}]$");
>
> }
> ```

---

[regex replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/844skk0h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (adapted here; strips out `` everything except A-Z, a-z , 0-9 and following characters. ~ ` ! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) _ + | - = \ { } [ ] : " ; ' < > ? , . / ``)

> ```
> String CleanInput(string strIn)
> {
>     // Replace invalid characters with empty strings.
>     return Regex.Replace(strIn,
>           @"[^a-zA-Z0-9`!@#$%^&*()_+|\-=\\{}\[\]:"";'<>?,./]", ""); 
> }
> ```

Concerning double quotes inside verbatim string literals: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gusperez/archive/2005/08/10/450257.aspx

Comment: Thanks @Jan Dvorak Can you give me RegEx which will strip out everything except A-Z, a-z , 0-9 and following characters.
~ ` ! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) _ + | - = \ { } [ ] : " ; ' < > ? , . /

Comment: @Nexus I've added an example how to regex-replace in C#

Comment: Thanks Once again. How do i allow double & single quotes from MS word in string ? “ ‘

Comment: @Nexus sorry buddy, I have no idea how to recognize which single and double quotes come from MS word. Allowing _all_ single and double quotes should be easy (note that they should already be allowed.)

Comment: US Keyboard's tilda and space characters are missing from the example. Here is the complete list: Regex.Replace(strIn, @"[^a-zA-Z0-9~`!@#$%^&*()_+|\-=\\{}\[\]:"";'<>?,./ ]", "")