# Make inputfield accept only english letters, numbers and symbols

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an input field and I want it to only accept English letters, numbers, and symbols. How can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [form validation allow only english alphabet characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15304790/form-validation-allow-only-english-alphabet-characters)

Comment: Not really, I can't use regex because I don't want non english letters to be inputed from the first place. I want only english letters real time. Could you show me a solution that involves the other one for a real time update?

Comment: Afaik you can in the Inspector or by code simply set its [`contentType`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.InputField-contentType.html) to [`ContentType.Custom`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.InputField.ContentType.Custom.html) and then define an alphabet that is allowed as input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a listener that changes the input field's value when it detects a change in value. And in that listener, set the value to be the same as the input but any non-compliant characters removed:

```
[SerializeField] InputField inputField;

void OnEnable()
{
    //Register InputField Event
    inputField.onValueChanged.AddListener(inputValueChanged});
}


static string CleanInput(string strIn)
{
    // Replace invalid characters with empty strings.
    return Regex.Replace(strIn,
          @"[^a-zA-Z0-9`!@#$%^&*()_+|\-=\\{}\[\]:"";'<>?,./]", ""); 
}

//Called when Input changes
void inputValueChanged(string attemptedVal)
{
    inputField.text = CleanInput(attemptedVal);
}

void OnDisable()
{
    //Un-Register InputField Events
    inputField.onValueChanged.RemoveAllListeners();
}
```

Sources:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/41392130/1092820
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/14682155/1092820